# Orthophotoplan cannot be viewed in openlayers due to HTTPS

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, tomcat, apache, http

I have the following problem on the server:

I have a server configured on HTTPS for apache and a TOMCAT that keeps GeoServer configured HTTP and when I try to bring images from GeoServer to OpenLayers then I get error:

> GET
> https://terra-apps.com:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&tiled=true&STYLES=&LAYERS=ADMINISTRATIE%3AORTO_GALBEANU&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&tilesOrigin=116269.96399989683%2C215882.49741375772&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A124&WIDTH=2595&HEIGHT=1238&BBOX=3007984.681182022%2C5646695.129897605%2C3044049.060891119%2C5663900.410082522
> net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Here is the code I'm trying with:

```js
new ol.layer.Group({
    'title': '> ORTOFOTOPLAN COMUNA/UAT',
    'layers': [
    
        new ol.layer.Image({
            // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
            title: 'ORTO test',
            // Again set this layer as a base layer
            type: 'base',
            visible: false,
            source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                  url: 'http://terra-apps.com:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms',
                  params: {'FORMAT': 'image/png', 
                           'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                           tiled: true,
                        "STYLES": '',
                        "LAYERS": 'ADMINISTRATIE:ORTO_GALBEANU',
                        "exceptions": 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage',
                     tilesOrigin: 116269.96399989683 + "," + 215882.49741375772
                  },
                  serverType: 'geoserver'
            }),
        }),
        
       ]
    }),
```

I specify that the same code, the same procedure on localhost on my computer works perfectly :(

I am very beginner to configure a tomcat server to have ssl and I have not managed this other solutions if possible?

Comment: Something fails with SSL handshaking. Test with curl `curl "https://terra-apps.com:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms?" -v` prints this: `* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1): * CONNECT phase completed!
* CONNECT phase completed! * error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`.

Comment: Sure because that server is not HTTPS:  curl "http://terra-apps.com:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms?" -v"

Comment: I took the address with https from your question. But I can't say where the http url that you have configured in OpenLayers code is changed into https.

Comment: the Geoserver server is on HTTP: http://terra-apps.com:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms and OpenLayers is on HTTPS as a result OpenLayers tries a request to geoserver on HTTPS although I specified HTTP in the url

Comment: If you want to access GeoServer via Apache then you should use apache's URL as the endpoint in the request (in fact GeoServer should not be visible from external sites)